# is there a reactive version of JpaSpecificationExecutor

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc

I have the following code which uses `Specification` to build complex where clause.

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends
    CrudRepository<Employee, String>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee> {
}

public class Service {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;


   public List<Employee> test() {
      return employeeRepository.findAll(where(hasNames(List.of("Tom", "Jerry"))).and(hasAges(List.of(20,21))));
   }
}
```

I'm trying to convert this code to reactive using the r2dbc. I replaced `CrudRepository` with `ReactiveCrudRepository`. However in order to build the complex where clause I need to use `Specification`. I don't see a reactive version of `JpaSpecificationExecutor`

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends
    ReactiveCrudRepository<Employee, String>,
    JpaSpecificationExecutor<Employee> { // is there ReactiveJpaSpecificationExecutor?
}
```

Is there a reactive version of JpaSpecificationExecutor, or a way to build such where clause in reactive?

Answer (score 0):

I also waiting for Criteria, but I didn't see now ;-)
I need to implement beetwen: [Spring JPA ExampleMatcher compare date condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45973070/spring-jpa-examplematcher-compare-date-condition)

See also similar questions:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1331
https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-spi/issues/141

Maybe you can use Template at the moment:
https://hantsy.medium.com/update-accessing-rdbms-with-spring-data-r2dbc-a4d118b1669d or infobip-spring-data-querydsl

Answer (score 0):

I use ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor for that

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Employee, Long>, ReactiveQuerydslPredicateExecutor<Employee> {
    
    Flux<Employee> findAll(Predicate predicate);
    Mono<Employee> findOne(Predicate predicate);
    Mono<Long> count(Predicate predicate);        
}
```